# Python: Check if a index in a list was set

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to migrate the following JavaScript code to Python.

```
// return the nth term in Fibonacci series
var fib = function () {
    var memo = [0, 1];

    return function fib(n) {
        if (typeof memo[n] !== 'number') { // check if memo[n] is available
            memo[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        }
        return memo[n];
    };
}();
```

However, it seems there is no way in Python to determine if a index in a list, corresponding to the JavaScript code `typeof memo[n] !== 'number'`.

Comment: If you get an `IndexError`, it wasn't set. Otherwise, the value was initialised.

Comment: So there is no function in Python like isset() in PHP?

Comment: Given I don't know PHP, sorry, I wouldn't know.

Comment: I posted my version of this in Python to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101487/recursive-fibonacci-generator-that-tries-to-guard-against-too-much-recursion) if you're interested in seeing how I tried to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) principle is employed. It's Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission. This means that you should just assume the index exists and wrap it in a `try except` so you can catch when the index is missing. It'd look like this:

```
try:
    list[i]
except IndexError:
    # list has no index i
```

This is a common usage in Python, because it's actually faster than first checking if the index is valid and then calling it. It's especially fast if the indices you'd supply usually are valid and you only occasionally need to catch incorrect values.

In your particular case, this would be a good format:

```
try:
    return memo[n]
except IndexError:
    # Calculate the answer since it's not stored
    memo.append( fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) )
    return memo[n]
```

Comment: Because we have no way of knowing that the memo is going to be added to in proper numerical order, I would suggest using a dictionary for memoization.  Even if the OP plans to build the memo in order, there are a lot of use scenarios where the flexibility of a dictionary would be to our advantage.

Comment: @kingsandman Generally that would be true, but since this is a fibonacci sequence then it could actually call itself recursively and removes that issue by generating all the other values it needs.

Comment: Oops! I forgot that you cannot dynamically add an index into a list, which is contrarily true in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
memo = [0,1]
def fib(n):
    if len(memo) <= n:
        memo.append(fib(n-2) + fib(n-1))
    return memo[n]
print fib(1)
```

you can use len function to check if the index exceeds the list's length
previous js code can be written in python like this:

Comment: It seems that LBYL--Look before you leap--is not a common Python coding style as well as a good practice. [This is why](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl)